# iOS font name from kCTFontManagerRegisteredFontsChangedNotification notification?

Tags: ios, core-text

I'm loading font's remotely by making a url request, creating a `CGFontRef` from data, and registering it with `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont`. If I use the same data and call `CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorFromData` I can get the font name.
If I register for the notification and then try to get the name, I'm not having any luck. I get back that the URL doesn't exist. If I loop through the `[UIFont familyNames]` I see that it exists, the problem is having prior knowledge to what I'm loading. Can this be done without creating my own notifications or alternative to pass the name around?

```
lldb: po note
__CFNotification 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF {name = CTFontManagerFontChangedNotification; userInfo = {
 CTFontManagerAvailableFontURLsAdded =     (
   "file://..."
 );
}}

- (void)noteHandler:(NSNotification *)note{
  NSDictionary *userInfo = [note userInfo];
  NSURL *fileURL = (NSURL *)([userInfo objectForKey:@"CTFontManagerAvailableFontURLsAdded"][0]);

  CFErrorRef error;
  Boolean reachable = CFURLResourceIsReachable((__bridge CFURLRef)(fileURL), &error);
  // error says file does not exist.
  CFArrayRef descriptors =  CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromURL((__bridge CFURLRef)(fileURL));
  // null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this. It's common on stack overflow to talk about using `CGDataProviderRef`, `CGFontCreateWithDataProvider` and then registering with `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont`. The problem is that the notification doesn't give you a valid URL that you can use for the URL calls within CoreText api's.
The better way to load the font is by writing to a tmp url first, then registering that url. Then the notification passes the tmp url along.
Here's the full example..

```
NSURL *remoteLocation;
NSData *remoteContent;
...
NSString *path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[url.pathComponents componentsJoinedByString:@""]];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSError *error = nil;
if ([inData writeToURL:fileURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error]) {
    CFErrorRef cferror;
    if (CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL, kCTFontManagerScopeProcess, &cferror)) {
        // You take it from here..
    }
}
```

Now in the notification assuming all goes well..

```
[theNoteCenter addObserver:self
                  selector:@selector(registeredFontChange:)
                      name:(NSString *)kCTFontManagerRegisteredFontsChangedNotification
                    object:nil];

- (void)registeredFontChange:(NSNotification *)note {
     NSDictionary *userInfo = [note userInfo];
     CFURLRef fileURL = (__bridge CFURLRef)([userInfo objectForKey:@"CTFontManagerAvailableFontURLsAdded"][0]);
     CFArrayRef allDescriptors = CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromURL(fileURL);
     // I only happen to get a single descriptor
     CTFontDescriptorRef descriptor = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allDescriptors, 0);
     CFStringRef name = CTFontDescriptorCopyAttribute(descriptor, kCTFontNameAttribute);
     // Now you can use this font [UIFont fontWithName:... size:...]    
}
```